Multiple exec commands running in the background in shell script
I am finding it difficult to understand how the processes are launched in such a shell script
mainscript.sh
exec command1 &
sleep 10
exec command2 &
sleep 10

I understand that exec command does not create a new process it just replaces the bash with the command to be executed, in that case, what happens when it runs with an &
Currently I see this is the ps output something like this
UID      PID   PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
user+    1       0  0 16:43 ?        00:00:00 bash mainscript.sh
user+    48      1  9 16:43 ?        00:00:04 command1
user+    133     1  0 16:43 ?        00:00:00 command2


if you add an ampersand to your command exec will no longer have effect! Job is run in background. U could get his pid in $!!


what happens when it runs with an &

First a subshell is created on &.
user+    1       0  0 16:43 ?        00:00:00 bash mainscript.sh
user+    48      1  9 16:43 ?        00:00:04 bash mainscript.sh

Then that subshell is replaced by command1.
user+    1       0  0 16:43 ?        00:00:00 bash mainscript.sh
user+    48      1  9 16:43 ?        00:00:04 command1

The whole line, including exec, it run in a subshell.
Note: without exec, in this case you will most probably see the same result. This is because Bash has an optimization, that if a (sub-)shell will execute only single process (and there are also some other conditions), then Bash will exec automatically to conserve resources and reduce processes count on the system.

In my case PID 48 remains as mainscript and then creates a child process for command1. When would this happen?

Then pid 48 will stay and another pid will run as command1.

Is there a way that i can avoid keeping 48 as mainscript and have the child process replace it? I've tried several options, but I am unable to replace the subshell with the child process

I do not follow. So do not start the child at all. Your question shows how to replace it - using exec. Also, your computer has gigabytes of memory, who cares about one process.

Sorry, I might have not been very clear. I'm running these in a docker and want to have as few processes as possible. My issue is that I need command1 to run in the background, and have the subshell (mainscript running as 48) be replaced by command1.

I'm running these in a docker exactly, so who cares about one process. Docker is running tens of processes just to set up itself. My point being, optimizing single count of processes is rather ineffective. I need command1 to run in the background, and have the subshell (mainscript running as 48) be replaced by command1 that is a contradiction. I still do not follow, this is exactly what happens in your question.
